# How to locate event handlers for OK and Help button in mfc?

Tags: visual-c++

I am new to MFC. In the project I am working on the dialogs are created in resource file(.rc).
In that there are OK button(id `ID_OK`) and Help button (id `ID_Help`). I am not able to find the event handlers for these two buttons. There are other buttons where the event handlers mapped are easily found. If someone teach me how to find those event handlers it would be very helpful.

And how can I find the functions which get called on clicking of the particular button by debugging in visual studio?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Double click the button (shown in rc) opened in Resource View in Visual Studio and you will be automatically placed by Studio where the Event handler is located in your code.

If this does not work, then probably delete the Button with ID's `ID_OK` and `ID_Help` in your resource view and again add it to the resource using different ID and then try to generate the event handler by double-clicking those buttons in resource view. This is because sometimes the value of ID's conflict with other ID values and hence Studio is not able to generate the Event-handler for you in that case.

Answer (score 0):

1. Buttons don't have direct event handlers as in other frameworks (like in C#, WinForms etc). You must use message-maps in MFC.
2. `ID_OK` maps to virtual function `CDialog::OnOK`, you can just write your virtual function implementation. Framework will call it for you. You can also handle this message with `WM_COMMAND` message entry.
3. There is no standard resource ID as `ID_Help` - it is always capital, and has to be always in caps! No one is stopping you from using small letters, though - it for consistency and better readability.
4. Instead of fiddling with resource files (.RC and resource.h), mapping the same with your dialog class and things like that. I suggest you to go, and learn, without resource file. Start with drawing in frame (circles, filled-triangles whatever). Learn and know why virtual function are there for some messages, and message-maps for other (most) messages.

My two cents.